# having trouble with a complex numbers problem

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm pretty good at this stuff, but sometimes I come across questions like this:

$$e^z = e^w,  \quad z, w \in \mathbb{C}.$$

choose the correct answers:

A: $z=w$

B: $|z| = |w|$

C: $e^{iz} = e^{iw}$

D: $e^{2z} = e^{2w}$

can anyone explain what are the correct answers and why?

thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Consider the complex numbers $z=0$ and $w=i 2 \pi$ and check every option. What do you find?

Answer (score 2):

Hint for all:

$$z=0\,,\;\,w=2\pi i$$

Comment: so D is correct only?

Comment: ah ok i got it... thanks don and fantini for the hint!